# Excel 2010 is repeating the optioned text in a data-validated cell. Is this a bug?

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I have a table column that has data validation applied. It was working fine for a while, but now all of the entries are repeated – as in, if the option selected from the dropdown is "Per Diem," Excel displays "Per DiemPer Diem" in the cell. The formula bar shows the single version when the cell is selected. Is this a bug? Saving/restarting Excel does not clear the problem. Nor does zooming in/out, scrolling around, recalculate, or anything else.

Here is [a link to a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1eFO.png), since I cannot post images directly.

Answer (score 0):

I had `Format Cells \ Alignment \ Horizontal` set to `Fill`.

Sorry, folks...